# Does an boto S3Connection expire?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

Well, I feel a bit like an idiot asking this, but I can't tell from reading the source.

For how long can I reuse a boto `S3Connection` and `Bucket` before they need to be 'refreshed' (if they do at all)?

For instance, if I have a class which stores these two pieces as instance variables.

```
MyClass(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = S3Connection(awskey, etc..)
        self.bucket = self.conn.get_bucket('bucketname')


    # bunch of methods that use the bucket
```

My question is, assuming a single instance of this class that is reused, and given a long running web process, will storing the bucket like this eventually bite me by timing out or something? Should I be refreshing the connection every X minutes?

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hang on to those connections indefinitely.  If the underlying HTTP connection is closed by the server side, boto will automatically refresh the connection.  It should all be handled for you automatically.

Comment: Are you sure about this? https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/564 + linked issue (by you and others!) suggest otherwise. Also I'm seeing: volumes = ec2_conn.get_all_volumes(volume_ids=volumes_ids)
...
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>RequestExpired</Code><Message>Request has expired.</Message></Error></Errors>

Comment: Btw, I'm using v2.40